# Wierd error while saving code

Tags: permission-sets

I am saving following code but getting below error

```
        List<PermissionSet> allPermissionSets = [SELECT Description, 
                                                IsOwnedByProfile,
                                                Label, 
                                                Name, 
                                                NamespacePrefix, 
                                                ProfileId, 
                                                UserLicenseId
                                            FROM PermissionSet];
```

[image]

I am running the same code in other orgs works fine. Is there any setting that I am missing? Any thoughts?

Comment: Very weird! The code compiles in my org. What API version is the code using?

Comment: @BarCotter 30.0

Comment: I just tested on a class set to API 30 and could not reproduce your error.

Comment: Is there a class named PermissionSet in your org?

Comment: @RitikaBhrgv PermissionSet is a standard object provided by the salesforce.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. If there is by any chance a class defined in the org with the same name as an object or some special keyword (it could be an inner class also within the class where your query has been defined), the list declared will refer to the class instead of the object and can cause the error such as above.

Comment: @RitikaBhrgv You are right. I had created one class with same name PermissionSet. After deleting it, code saves. Please post the solution. I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is by any chance a class defined in the org with the same name as an object or some special keyword (it could be an inner class also within the class where your query has been defined), the list declared will refer to the class instead of the object and can cause the error such as above.